# Description property dont give back result

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to list all of groups without description.
I am trying to export a csv with name and description for manage the result list but there is no description in finish.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | select name, Description | export-csv -path c:\temp\grouplistanddescription.csv
```

Comment: the AD cmdlets DO NOT return all the properties when called. they return a default minimal set. [*grin*] if you want that prop, then include it in the property parameter of the AD call.

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Description
```

or

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties *
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick reaction. Next step is coming more difficult. I would like to know if groups are empty / if number of coutain objects = 0

Comment: Then I would suggest research the If statement. There are bound to be other people on this very website who have asked the same question. If you continue to have issues, I would suggest opening a new question with what you have tried and what is specifically going wrong.